# Finding the closest store using the users (and stores) coordinates

Tags: php, mongodb, database

I have a mongo collection of store locations complete with coordinates. I am creating an app that will get the users coordinates and find the closest store to their location. What is the most effective way to sort through the stores to get the result. How do I then get how many miles away the store is?

I am using the standard PHP mongo driver.

Comment: Do you have country, state and city data for each store? Also, how many stores are there?

Comment: Direct distance or driving distance?

Comment: I do have that data. Direct distance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MongoDB GeoSpatial query to perform this query.  This feature is documented here:  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the very last part of your question "How do I then get how many miles away the store is?", you can use the Google Maps API to find out the driving distance between the current location and the nearest store. As for the first bit, I need more information, which I've alluded to in the comments.